# Recursive Sort Function

Tags: c, recursion

I've written a program to recursively sort an array. 
However, I get the following error on line 11: syntax error before ']' token.

Here is the code:

```
//This program recursively sorts an array

#include<stdio.h>

void rec_sort(int values[], int n); 

main()
{
    int vals[4];
    vals[0] = 37; vals[1] = 48; vals[2] = 56; vals[3] = 63;
    printf("this array sorted: %x\n", rec_sort(vals[], 4));

    system("Pause"); 
    return 0;
}

void rec_sort(int values[], int n) {
//Base case
if (n<2) return;

int maxIndex=0;
int i;

//Find max item in array in indexes 0 through n-1
for(i=1; i<n;i++) {
      if(values[i] > values[maxIndex])
         maxIndex=i;

    }

    //Swap this element with one stored in n-1
    //Set temp to n-1, set n-1 in array to max, set max to temp
    int temp = values[n-1]; //Store temp as last element in array
    values[n-1] = values[maxIndex]; //Store last element as max value in array
    values[maxIndex] = temp; //temp will keep on changing, as array is sorted

    //Recursively sort the array values of length n-1
    sort(values, n-1); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying print out the whole array, which C won't do in one call to `printf`. Instead, you need a loop to iterate through the array and print out each number individually:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    printf("%x\n", vals[i]);
```

Since `rec_sort` isn't returning the array, you also need to invoke it separately from the call the printf, so you'd get something like:

```
// sort the data:
rec_sort(vals, 4);

// print the sorted values:
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    printf("%x\n", vals[i]);
```

Comment: i forgot that C isn't as flexible as java. Now I get the following error: undefined reference to sort

Comment: @Krysten, look at the bottom `sort(values, n-1);` It's a typo! `:)`

Comment: It compiles and run. But now i get funky numbers: 25 30 38 3f

Comment: @Krysten, how do you print them ? It is obvious you are still using `%x` in your `printf()` look at this answer and change `%x` to `%d`.

Comment: @Krysten: I used `%x` only because your original code did. `%x`, however, formats numbers in hexadecimal. If you want them in decimal, change it to `%d`.

Comment: perfect it works now. and i was under the impression that %x is used for printing out elements of an array. thanks!

Comment: "i forgot that C isn't as flexible as java." You wouldn't be able to write the code like this in Java either. `[]` is still not a part of the name of the variable; and a function that returns `void` still returns `void` (and thus you can't use its return value in an expression).

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `[]` on line 11. But this is a naive answer to your question, and won't get you far. There are other problems - the most obvious is the idea of `printf(..., rec_sort(...)...);`

Considering `rec_sort` has `void` return type, how do you expect `printf()` to understand what to do? I am not sure what you want either, but this should be at least a start for you.

Comment: I imagine its because rec_sort is void or because you are supposed to use qsort in C

Comment: would I have to write the function for qsort or is it built in C already?

Comment: @Krysten: yes, C has `qsort` in the standard library.

Comment: @Krysten "would I have to write the function for qsort or is it built in C already?" That's a question you should ask *before* writing your own sort routine. And having seen someone refer to qsort, it's one you can readily answer for yourself, by googling qsort. You might learn that qsort is an implementation of the quicksort algorithm, and that it is considerably faster (O(nlogn)) for large arrays than your routine, which is O(n*n).

Comment: @Jim How exactly is my routine O(n*n)?

Comment: @Krysten rec_sort(n) performs n iterations and then calls rec_sort(n-1). All told there are n + n-1 + ... + 1 iterations, which is n*(n+1)/2 which is O(n*n).

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("this array sorted: %x\n", rec_sort(vals[], 4));
```

but `rec_sort()` is `void`. Doesn't `return` anything

```
void rec_sort(int values[], int n)
```

Also, declare your main as `int main()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this:

```
rec_sort(vals[], 4)
```

What exactly do you want to do there? The `[]` is an index operation, so either you need to put a number in there, or you leave them out completely (if you want to talk about the whole array).

Comment: The OP made the sensible assumption that, since rec_sort has a values[] parameter, it can be called with a vals[] argument. As it is, though, one cannot program by making such assumptions, one must actually learn the rules of a programming language. But why bother to learn anything if you can just come to SO whenever anything doesn't work? Hopefully those who take that approach will eventually learn that they can't get very far with it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is remove the square brackets:

```
printf("this array sorted: %x\n", rec_sort(vals, 4));
```

Second, note that rec_sort returns void, so you cant use the return value

you need

```
int i; // at the top of the main
// ...
rec_sort(vals, 4);
printf("this array sorted: ");
for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%x ", vals[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Third: you need to call rec_sort again

Fourth: what are you tryin to do with the `system` statement?

Comment: "Third: you need an implementation of sort (are you sure you dont mean qsort?)" No, she obviously means rec_sort -- it's supposed to be recursive.